# В чем причина близости семантически разных слов?

Tags: этимология

Я не буду вспоминать слова из этой группы, обсуждавшиеся ранее, но трудно не заметить, что близки фонетически 1) кандалы и скандал, 2) боты/ботинки и бутик/(страшно сказать) аптека, или же бутылка. Можно ли обнаружить то общее, что лежит в основе этой близости, или это случайность, как часто считают? Каким образом можно найти ту точку, пройдя которую протокорни этих слов стали расходиться?

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи VVM и Shamov видидимо находятся под воздействием идей Чудинова или Задорнова. Или прото троллят форум.  
В здаравом же уме обсуждать подобное под заголовком о семантической близости считаю невозможным. Ни о какой семантической близости и речи быть не может.    
 

Comment: Спасибо за предельно содержательный ответ. Вы, как всегда, блестяще расставили все точки над и.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Надеюсь в следующий раз вы не станете меня утруждать подобной работой.

Comment: К сожалению, без вас мы вообще ничего не можем. Скорее всего ваша помощь потребуется нам ещё не раз.

Comment: behemothus, 
Вы опять вместо конструктивного обсуждения темы навешиваете ярлыки. Лучше скажите, Вы видите нечто общее в словах бутик и бутылка, и в чем причина этого, по Вашему мнению, а артиста Задорнова оставьте его зрителям: он смешит, как может.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу подчеркнуть, что я говорю о семантически различных словах, потому что бутик означает магазин, бутылка - стеклянную емкость, хотя слово магазин  в русском языке используется и как емкость (магазин с патронами), боты или ботинки имеют ту же особенность. У них есть общее, что трудно отрицать, поскольку они обозначают "емкость" в широком смысле этого слова. Они явно восходят к одному протокорню, чем объяняется их фонетическая близость, соответственно, их созвучие не случайно. В других языках это просматривается: например, bath (англ., ванна, погружаться в воду).

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что в большинстве случаев фонетическая близость не обусловлена ничем. Ведь те же самые слова могут не быть близкими в других языках. А вот в тех случаях, когда они близки не только в русском, но и в других языках, скорее всего, между ними действительно есть какая-то связь. Если не семантическая, то, по крайней мере, историческая. Видимо, это и есть основной ключ к поиску протокорней - нужно сравнивать степень близости слов в разных языках.

Comment: Эта фонетическая близость не случайна, поскольку конкретные слова фиксируются и застывают в определенных словоформах, а этимологическая идея, заложенная в их корне, развивается, воплощаясь в новых словах, если возникает потребность передать какой-то конкретный смысл (то, что называется смыслом, значением, или семантическим значением слова). Если бутыль(по Фасмеру) отмечена в использовании в русском языке с 1694 года, то слово пузо или пузырь (трансформация того же корня и воплощение той же идеи) идет с гораздо более раннего времени. Пузо - не бутыль, но бутыль - это еще и пузырек.